# Conflict for System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe between Npgsql and System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-6, npgsql

I have downloaded EntityFramework6.Npgsql 6.4.0 nuget.
As a dependent, Npgsql 4.1.2 was installed along with the nuget.

While running the code, observed following error:

```
=== Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = **System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.5.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Agilent Technologies/Sample Scheduler for OpenLab/Bin/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL Calling assembly : Npgsql, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7.
=== LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: No application configuration file found. LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config. LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/X/Y/Bin/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.DLL. WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Revision Number ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

To fix this, I have copied the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.5.0 into my Bin directory.

After this, I got the following error:

```
=== Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = **System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Agilent Technologies/Sample Scheduler for OpenLab/Bin/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL Calling assembly : System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51.
=== LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: No application configuration file found. LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config. LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/X/Y/Bin/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.DLL. WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Revision Number ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Due to this incompatible dependency on the same library with different versions, I could not go forward.

Please help, how to fix this.

Comment: Npgsql 4.1.2 depends on System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe version 4.6.0, do you have something else depending on an earlier version? You may be able to resolve this simply by adding a [binding redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions). Otherwise, can you please link to a full runnable project somewhere so we can take a look?

Comment: Binding redirect is already present in my App.config file as follows:


 <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.5.0" newVersion="4.0.5.0" />

I could compile the code. Observing above mentioned errors at run time,

Comment: Considering that Npgsql 4.1.2 depends on 4.6.0, can you try changing you binding redirects to redirect to that? Otherwise again, a link to a minimal project with this issue would help.

Comment: I am really new to .Net and C#.
While adding the nuget, my app.config updated automatically.

Comment: @ShayRojansky I tried with a sample application, in which I tried to create the database and insert data using CodeFirst approach. It is working fine with this nuget, where as I am facing issues with my actual app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @ShayRojansky inputs.
I added binding redirects in my app.config file.

My application have an Entity library which will do all the DB operations.
I added Nugets for this Entity library project in my VS.

After the build, these binding redirects not added to my application app config.
I manually updated the EXE.app.config and this issue is resolved.